# Excel Format duplicate values - change the text in the cell

Tags: excel, duplicate-data

It is very easy to format the cells that have duplicated values (like setting specific background on them or something other style) using the "Conditional formatting", but how can I change their text?

For example:

> A1 2332
>
> A2 2333
>
> A3 2334
>
> A4 2334

to become:

> A1 2332
>
> A2 2333
>
> A3 2334(1)
>
> A4 2334(2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to just add a second column next to your original data with the following formula filled down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$5000,A1)>1,A1& " (" & COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1) & ")",A1)
```

where your original data is in A1:A5000.  Beware that `COUNTIF` is pretty inefficient, so if you have a lot of data, this could take a while to calculate and affect your workbook performance.

For a large workbook, I'd consider using a VBA Worksheet_Change event to edit the values in place.  This code should be inserted in the appropriate Worksheet module. On 5000 test records it had a couple second lag.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim dataRng As Range
Dim dataArr() As Variant, output() As String
Dim y As Long, i As Long, j As Long, tmpcount As Long

'Change "A1" to address of start of column you want to index.
Set dataRng = Range("A1").Resize(Me.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1)
If Not Intersect(Target, dataRng) Is Nothing Then
    dataArr = dataRng.Value
    ReDim output(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    'Strip old counts from data once in array.
    For y = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        If Right(dataArr(y, 1), 1) = ")" Then
            dataArr(y, 1) = Left(dataArr(y, 1), InStr(dataArr(y, 1), " (") - 1)
        End If
    Next y

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        tmpcount = 0
        output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
            If dataArr(i, 1) = dataArr(j, 1) Then
                tmpcount = tmpcount + 1
                If j = i And tmpcount > 1 Then
                    output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1) & " (" & tmpcount & ")"
                    Exit For
                End If
                If j > i And tmpcount > 1 Then
                    output(i, 1) = dataArr(i, 1) & " (" & tmpcount - 1 & ")"
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Call printoutput(output, dataRng)
End If

End Sub


Private Sub printoutput(what As Variant, where As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
where.Value = what
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Beware I've made a couple of big assumptions:

1. I assumed the column you want to index starts at A1.  If it is in another column, you will need to adjust line 7 of the code.
2. I assumed your data will never end in ")" unless it has previously been indexed.  If that's not the case, stay away from this code!